# Get image Embedded Resources in code

Tags: java, imagesource, getresource

Here is my code

```
package test;

import javax.swing.*;
import static javax.swing.JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE;


public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame f=new JFrame("Photo");
        JLabel p=new JLabel(new ImageIcon("flower.jpg"));
        f.add(p);
        f.pack();
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setVisible(true);


    }
}
```

See this photos

[The folder of my project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ZVnf.png)

[The folder in which my source code and resource (images)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A5aIX.png)

How can i access the images in images folder by get resources instead of `"flower.jpg"`  which work only if i put the image in the folder of the program  ?

Modify in this code

```
JLabel p=new JLabel(new ImageIcon("flower.jpg"));
```

to show the image from resources

I need to use get resource but how ? this is my question

Comment: Did you try with "images/flower.jpg"?

Comment: `new ImageIcon("/absolute/package/name/to/your/image/flower.jpg")` 
or 
`new ImageIcon("relative/package/name/to/your/image/flower.jpg")`

Comment: I need to use get resource but how ?  this is my question